# Заменить все руссские символы на английские и наоборот

Tags: java, замена

Вопрос такой как перебрать в одном слове все похожие буквы из русского алфавита и английского например есть слово джава его можно написать как дж***a***ва и джав***a*** и дж***a***в***a*** (жирным курсивом выделены буквы из латинского алфавита), как сделать чтобы это делало само?  Пытался что то сделать но заменяет все символы

Comment: Одну букву на другую в строке Java вы заменить сумеете? Составить список замен сумеете?

Comment: конкретнее вопрос поставь пожалуйста, а то про слово джава и джава я не понимаю...

Comment: @tym32167 что то похожее да

Comment: @GorgeousBoris типо джава где a - английский и так все варианты где две 2 английские где в конце английская

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy делал но меняются все русские на английские а не перебором где например a в начале потом a в конце а потом вместе

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем HashMap из необходимых замен:

```java
Map<Character, Character> substitutions = new HashMap<>();
substitutions.put('а', 'A');
substitutions.put('е', 'E');
substitutions.put('р', 'P');
```

Считаем количество букв `count`, которые нужно заменить в исходной строке `input`:

```java
String input = "привет";
int count = 0;
for (char character : input.toCharArray()) {
    if (substitutions.containsKey(character)) {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Генерируем список всех возможных комбинаций `binaryStrings` в бинарном представлении. Попутно дополняем строки недостающими нулями:

```java
List<String> binaryStrings = new ArrayList<>();
long pow = (long) Math.pow(2, count);
for (long i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
    String binaryString = Long.toBinaryString(i);
    char[] leadingZeros = new char[count - binaryString.length()];
    Arrays.fill(leadingZeros, '0');
    binaryStrings.add(String.valueOf(leadingZeros) + binaryString);
}

// binaryStrings на выходе будет списком из строк:
// ["00", "01", "10", "11"]
```

Наконец, делаем необходимые замены, каждому элементу списка `binaryStrings` сопоставляем новую строку. Символ `'0'` в `binaryString` соответствует тому, что замену делать не нужно, а символ `'1'` означает, что нужно сделать замену на символ в соответствии с `substitutions`:

```java
List<String> outputList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String binaryString : binaryStrings) {
    char[] binaryCharArray = binaryString.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    int index = 0;
    for (char character : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (substitutions.containsKey(character)) {
            if (binaryCharArray[index] == '0') {
                output.append(character);
            } else {
                output.append(substitutions.get(character));
            }
            index++;
        } else {
            output.append(character);
        }
    }
    outputList.add(output.toString());
}

// outputList на выходе будет содержать все возможные комбинации замен:
// ["привет", "привEт", "пPивет", "пPивEт"]
```